# Angular2: DI Issue - Injecting a service into another service results in an undefined service

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

I'm working on an `Angular 2.0.0-rc.4` project, and I'm having issues with dependency injection.

I have a notification service:

```
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

import { Notification } from '../../notifications/notification.model'

export class NotificationService {
  private notificationsSource: BehaviorSubject<Notification[]>;
  private dataStore: { notifications: Notification[] }

  constructor() {
    this.dataStore = { notifications: [] };
    this.notificationsSource = new BehaviorSubject<Notification[]>([]);
  }

  // Additional code //

}
```

The project uses `JwtAuthHttp` which we're extending into `AuthHttp`.  I'm injecting the `NotificationService` here for notifying of errors:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  Http,
  Request,
  Response,
  RequestOptionsArgs 
} from '@angular/http';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthHttp as JwtAuthHttp, AuthConfig } from 'angular2-jwt';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';

import { NotificationService } from './notification-service';

@Injectable()
export class AuthHttp extends JwtAuthHttp {
  constructor(
    options: AuthConfig,
    http: Http,
    private router: Router,
    private notificationService: NotificationService
  ) { super(options, http); }

  // Additional code //

  handleError(err: Response) {
    this.notificationService.add(err.json(), 'error');
    return Observable.throw(err)
  }
}
```

Both the `AuthHttp` and the `NotificationService` are being added as singleton providers in the `main.ts` file:

```
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
import { enableProdMode, provide } from '@angular/core';
import { disableDeprecatedForms, provideForms } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Http, HTTP_PROVIDERS } from '@angular/http';
import { bootstrap } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { Cookie } from 'ng2-cookies';
import { AuthConfig } from 'angular2-jwt';

import { APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS } from './app.routes';
import { NotificationService } from './shared/services/notification.service';
import { AuthHttp } from './shared/services/auth-http';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

if ('<%= ENV %>' === 'prod') { enableProdMode(); }

bootstrap(AppComponent, [
  disableDeprecatedForms(),
  provideForms(),
  APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
  HTTP_PROVIDERS,
  provide(APP_BASE_HREF, { useValue: '<%= APP_BASE %>' }),
  provide(AuthHttp, {
    useFactory: (http: Http, router: Router, notificationService: NotificationService) => {
      return new AuthHttp(new AuthConfig({
        noJwtError: true,
        tokenName: 'auth_token',
        tokenGetter: (() => Cookie.get('auth_token'))
      }), http, router, notificationService);
    },
    deps: [Http, Router, NotificationService]
  }),
  NotificationService
]);
```

I'm wanting to use the `handleError` method on `AuthHttp` for my services as a generic way of handling server errors with notifications (e.g. the following `PermissionService`:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/share';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/from';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

import { Config, AuthHttp, NotificationService } from '../../shared/index';
import { UserPermission } from './';
import { User } from './';

@Injectable()
export class PermissionService {
  public headers:Headers;
  private baseUrl:string = Config.API_URL;

  constructor(
    private http: AuthHttp,
    private notificationService: NotificationService
  ) { }

  getUserPermission(username: string): Observable<UserPermission> {
   return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}/user_permissions/${username}`)
    .map(response => response.json())
    .catch(this.http.handleError)
  }

  // Additional code //
}
```

However, when a server error occurs, I get the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined
>   at CatchSubscriber.AuthHttp.handleError [as selector]

So, for some reason, `NotificationService` is not being injected properly.  I've searched for several hours for an answer, and can't figure out what's wrong.

Comment: It doesn't look like NotificationService is marked `@Injectable()`.  From reading the docs it may not be required because it doesn't contain any injectable parameters itself, but it's recommended for all services.

Comment: @JasonGoemaat I kind of lean toward lean code. :)  But I added it and I'm getting the same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by changing `catch` in `getUserPermission` from:

```
.catch(this.http.handleError)
```

to:

```
.catch(err => this.http.handleError(err))
```

By giving `catch` just the function, it seems that it wasn't using the instance of `this.http` to call the function, but just running the function as a standalone.  Actually calling the function on `this.http` gave me no problems.